Django: unexpected keyword arguments when trying to create new object
I'm trying to create a new object but I keep getting an error

player_team() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'player', 'team'

I'm just starting out in Django and working on a personal project. I've tried my best to problem solve but I'm still getting this unexplained error.
Here is my model:
class player_team(models.Model):
    Player = models.ForeignKey(player, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Team = models.ForeignKey(team, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)

Here is my view
def assign_team(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        PlayersID = request.POST.get("Players")
        TeamsId = request.POST.get("Teams")
        player_team.objects.create(
            player = PlayersID,
            team = TeamsId
        )

        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])


if the class names of Player and Team are capitalized, i think you have it backwards in the ForeignKey statements. in other words, it should be player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE) because the foreign key is created on the class not the variable.

reference the ForeignKey creation in the first example in this Django documentation page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

you have written Player in models.py and player while creating the object so, I guess you have use either Player or player in both places.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
